# The lifetime of instance of object in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm still little bit perplexed by pointers and memory management (starting out with ObjC and Cocoa). What got me thinking, is this piece of code:

```
double seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

This is what I understand:

1. I get value of float type returned from calling method/message on NSDate class
2. This value gets stored in variable `seconds`

What I don't understand is am I creating `NSDate` object (=instance of class `NSDate`) at all? Is this object only temporary?
I always thought that the way to create an object and have the object to be persistent (at least until ARC steps in or it is destroyed when function ends) is to create a pointer to it. Maybe like this:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
[now timeIntervalSince1970] // get the value
```

Does this mean that in my original example, there is some unnamed (no variable pointing to it) instance of `NSDate` created on the heap and once it returns the float value it gets removed from heap?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that in my original example, there is some unnamed (no
>   variable pointing to it) instance of NSDate created on the heap and
>   once it returns the float value it gets removed from heap?

Yes, that's exactly right.

ARC will remove the object when it goes out of scope.

Even before ARC, the object would be created as `autorelease` and be released the next time through the event loop (or whenever the *nearest* autorelease pool was drained).

Comment: ok thanks I wanted to reassure myself. now I have another question concerning terminology.
in my first piece of code, is `timeIntervalSince19709` a class method? and in my second piece of code `[now timeIntervalSince1970]` an instance method then?

Comment: No, that method is an instance method, which is why you needed to use `[NSDate date]` to create an instance.  If it was a class method then you would have called `[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]`.

Comment: oh I see and it makes sense since I'm creating an instance but just not pointing to it using variable.

Comment: Making a class method does make sense to me and would be slightly more efficient (as there is no need to create an instance).  However it does introduce another method, thus slightly complicating the class.  It's not black and white; Apple like to provide fewer methods while Microsoft like to provide more (speaking as someone getting into C# programming via Unity).